# Is it possible to find out how many results were unexpected?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving

During a school year Andrew was given 40 mathematical problems as part of his assessment, one problem per week. As a result of marking he could receive 2,3,4 or 5 marks for each problem. Andrew called his result for any problem "unexpected" if up to that week the same mark occurred a lesser number of times than any other mark. For example, if for the first 10 problems, in order Andrew's marks were 3,4, ....,3, then his "unexpected" marks would have been 5 when it occurred for the first time, and 4 when it occurred for the second time. At the end of the year Andrew received 10 results of 2 marks each, 10 results of 3 marks each, 10 results of 4 marks each and 10 results of 5 marks each, though it not known in which order. Is it possible to determine for sure how many results were "unexpected" for Andrew?

I am still slightly unclear about what unexpected is and am not sure how I would prove whether or not it is possible to find the number of "unexpected" results for Andrew. I would  really appreciate easy-to understand explanations. Thank you.

Comment: I am also confused, in particular over this bit (my highlight): "Andrew called his result for any problem "unexpected" if up to that week the same mark occurred a lesser number of times than *any other mark*." Does "any other mark" mean "some other mark" or "all other marks"?

Comment: Also, the example is confusing to me. It looks line he has received the marks "3,4,3,3,...,3", and if a 5 occurs, it is unexpected, but this 5 is now at a tie with the 4-mark, so maybe it should have occured *at most* the same number of times as all other marks (that have occured so far) in order to be called unexpected. Also, does your example imply that if we have the sequence "3,4,3,...,3,5,4", then this last second-occuring 4 is unexpected? This seems to mean that you should just occur at most as much as the most typical mark in order to be unexpected.

Comment: I think it means "all other marks"